# How can I run flow in specific folder?

Tags: flowtype

I'm new to flow and react.
Is there a way to run flow in the specific folder?

```
npm run flow
```

shows too much error.

Shuold I change .flowconfig?

Is there js ninja?
thanks.

Comment: Can you add your output please ?

Comment: there too much flow's error.
npm run flow works well.
I don't want to remove // @flow from each file